I cant call C# functions inside of my blazor app
I am trying to build an login page, but when I tried adding a bit of C# code to change a eye icon from closed to open. It's for showing the password. The problem is that I think my C# code is not getting called.
@page "/"


<form> 
    <div class="head-container">
        <label class="head-label" >Login</label>
        <div class="username-container">
            <label class="username-label" >Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="username-input" />
        </div>

        <div class="password-container">
            <label class="password-label" >Password</label>
                <div class="passwordInp-container" >
                    <input type="password" class="password-input" id="password-input" />



                      <!-- This is the Image im trying to change -->
                  <img src="@imageURL" class="password-eye" @onclick="ShowPassword" id="eye"/>




                </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
        <p class="newUserPassword"><a href="" class="aTag">Register</a></p>
    </div>
</form> 


@code {
    public string imageURL = "/media/eye-closed.ico";

    public void ShowPassword()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("ShowPassword method called");

        if (imageURL == "/media/eye-closed.ico")
        {
            imageURL = "/media/eye-open.ico";
        }
        else
        {
            imageURL = "/media/eye-closed.ico";
        }
    }

}

Thanks for any help in advance!
I tried to to include a Console.WriteLine() in the function but even that wouldnt show. But the imageURL variable is being set to the desired path, so the code is running, just not the function.
Im not really sure what version of .NET I have, but I just installed it, the Interactive render mode is "Auto (Server and WebAssembly)" and the Interactivity location is "Per page/component"

Note that Console.WriteLine does not end up in the browser's javascript console. Try setting a breakpoint in that method. Does that get hit?

Net version?  Interactivity type? Interactivity location?  If Per Page location, your need to add the Render Mode. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Ok I'll add that

I just tested this, and the code you posted does work for me.
Are you sure that eye-closed.ico and eye-open.ico are not the same image?
What about doing the following:
@code {
    public string imageURL = "/media/eye-closed.ico";

    public void ShowPassword()
    {
        if (imageURL == "/media/eye-closed.ico")
        {
            imageURL = "";
        }
        else
        {
            imageURL = "/media/eye-closed.ico";
        }
    }

}

Does this make the image disappear when clicking it?
(Would have posted this as a comment but apparently need more rep to do that)

It stayed the same :(
